# fill curser not showing up in excel

Tags: excel

i am running into a excel issue that is causing me to pull my hair out...

Basically what is  happening is that when i want to use the Autofill option in excel the cursor for it will only show up about 10% of the time i try to use it.

instead the pointer [image: Pointer Thing] or this [image: Other Thing] will show up... i never use those other cursors and i want the fill cursor to come up when i hover the mouse in the bottom right of the cells like this [image: AutoFill Excel option]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this option under `File >> Options >> Advanced` and see it is appearing as below.

[image]

Comment: both those boxes are checked.